# Determine address family of an unbound socket

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, bind, winsock

When I try to bind my socket I need to specify the address family in the addrinfo/sockaddr-structure I pass in to the call to bind(), or one will get an winsock error 10047 (Address family not supported by protocol family.)

What if I created a socket elswhere not knowing its address family...
How could I get the address family for that socket, so i can bind it?

getsockname only works for bound sockets :/...

I don´t want to force the caller of my function to pass the address family to my functions, especially if she/he/it uses AF_UNSPEC/PF_UNSPEC when creating her/his socket

(e.g. `SOCKET sock = socket(AF_UNSPEC, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);` )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I am using Winsock I did search the MSDN for a short while and found WSADuplicateSocket.

```
WSAPROTOCOL_INFO proto;
WSADuplicateSocket(Socket, GetCurrentProcessId(), &proto);
SocketAF = proto.iAddressFamily;
```

Works fine for windows machines...

Comment: Also getsockopt with SO_PROTOCOL_INFO could be used for retrieve same information.